# PHP image upload memory limit reduction

Tags: php, memory-leaks, image-uploading, image-upload

I use a PHP file to upload images to my server from my web application and have recently hit some memory limit issues that I was hoping someone with more experience than me could help with. Most of the images uploaded have been from mobiles so the file size is very manageable but recently there have been some uploads from an SLR camera that have been causing the issues. These images are around 7-8MB in size and I had assumed our PHP memory limit of 64MB would handle this. Upon inspection I found the imagecreatefromjpeg() function in our crop function to be the culprit although I assume the memory has been filled up before this despite using imagedestroy() to clear any previously created images. Upon using ini_set('memory_limit') to up the limit to a much higher value I found the script worked as expected but I would prefer a cleaner solution. I have attached the code below and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

if(isset($_POST)) {
    ############ Edit settings ##############
    $ThumbSquareSize        = 200; //Thumbnail will be 200x200
    $ThumbPrefix            = "thumbs/"; //Normal thumb Prefix
    $DestinationDirectory   = '../../../uploads/general/'; //specify upload directory ends with / (slash)
    $PortfolioDirectory   = '../../../images/portfolio/';
    $Quality                = 100; //jpeg quality
    ##########################################

    $imID = intval($_POST['imageID']);
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $data = $image['data'];
    $name = $image['name']; //get image name
    $width = $image['width']; // get original image width
    $height = $image['height'];// orig height
    $type = $image['type']; //get file type, returns "image/png", image/jpeg, text/plain etc.
    $desc = $image['desc'];
    $album = intval($image['album']);
    $customer = intval($image['customer']);
    $tags = $image['tags'];
    $allTags = $_POST['allTags'];
    $portType = intval($image['portType']);
    $rating = intval($image['rating']);
    $imData = array();

    if(strlen($data) < 500) {
        $dParts = explode('?', $data);
        $path = $dParts[0];
        $base64 = file_get_contents($path);
        $data = 'data:' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($base64);
    }

    function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {
        $ifp = fopen($output_file, "wb");

        $data = explode(',', $base64_string);

        fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data[1]));
        fclose($ifp);

        return $output_file;
    }

    function base64_to_png($base64_string, $output_file) {

        $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $base64_string);
        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
        $data = base64_decode($img);

        $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
        if ($im !== false) {
            imagepng($im, $output_file);
            imagedestroy($im);
        }

        return $output_file;
    }


   if($stmt = $db -> prepare("UPDATE `images` SET name = ?, type = ?, description = ?, width = ?, height = ?, rating = ?, portType = ?, customer = ?, album = ?, dateModified = NOW() WHERE ID = ?")) {


      $stmt -> bind_param("sssiiiiiii", $name, $type, $desc, $width, $height, $rating, $portType, $customer, $album, $imID);

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo false;
        } else {


            $delTags = "DELETE FROM tagLink WHERE imageID = $imID";
            if(!$db->query($delTags)) {
                echo $db->error;
            }

            if(sizeof($tags) > 0) {
                foreach($tags as $tag) {
                    $tagQ = "INSERT INTO tagLink (imageID, tag) VALUES ($imID, '$tag')";
                    if(!$db->query($tagQ)) {
                        echo $db->error;
                    }
                }
            }

            switch(strtolower($type))
            {
                case 'png':
                    $fname = $name . '(' . $imID . ').png';
                    $file = $DestinationDirectory . $fname;
                    $portfile = $PortfolioDirectory . $fname;
                    $thumbDest = $DestinationDirectory . $ThumbPrefix . $fname;
                    $CreatedImage = base64_to_png($data,$file);

                    break;
                case 'jpeg':
                case 'pjpeg':
                case 'jpeg':

                    $fname = $name . '(' . $imID . ').jpeg';
                    $file = $DestinationDirectory . $fname;
                    $portfile = $PortfolioDirectory . $fname;
                    $thumbDest = $DestinationDirectory . $ThumbPrefix . $fname;
                    $CreatedImage = base64_to_jpeg($data,$file);

                    break;
                default:
                    die('Unsupported File!'); //output error and exit
            }

            array_push($imData, $imID);
            array_push($imData, $name);
            array_push($imData, $type);
            array_push($imData, $portType);


            echo json_encode($imData);

            if(!cropImage($width,$height,$ThumbSquareSize,$thumbDest,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$type))
            {
                echo 'Error Creating thumbnail';
            }


        }

        $stmt -> close();


   } else {
     /* Error */
     printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $db->error);
   }

       /* Close connection */
   $db -> close();

    include '../cron/updatePortfolio.php';



}


//This function corps image to create exact square images, no matter what its original size!
function cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$iSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$type)
{
    //Check Image size is not 0
    if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if($CurWidth>$CurHeight)
    {
        $y_offset = 0;
        $x_offset = ($CurWidth - $CurHeight) / 2;
        $square_size    = $CurWidth - ($x_offset * 2);
    }else{
        $x_offset = 0;
        $y_offset = ($CurHeight - $CurWidth) / 2;
        $square_size = $CurHeight - ($y_offset * 2);
    }


    switch(strtolower($type))
    {
        case 'png':
        $imageX = imagecreatefrompng ( $SrcImage );
        break;
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'pjpeg':
        case 'jpeg':
        $imageX = imagecreatefromjpeg ( $SrcImage );
        break;
        default:
        return false;
    }



    $NewCanves  = imagecreatetruecolor($iSize, $iSize);
    if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $imageX, 0, 0, $x_offset, $y_offset, $iSize, $iSize, $square_size, $square_size))
    {
        switch(strtolower($type))
        {
            case 'png':
                imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;
            case 'jpeg':
            case 'pjpeg':
            case 'jpeg':
                imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,$Quality);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        if(is_resource($NewCanves)) {
            imagedestroy($NewCanves);
        }

        return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: What could be cleaner. You have one script that requires extra memory and you have amended that script to allow itself the required memory.

Comment: You have encapsulated the ability to inc memory and it is self documenting

Comment: I was just hoping there was some obvious memory leak I was missing that was causing the large memory usage. Is it usual for an 8MB image upload to require 256MB of memory?

Comment: Does it require `256M` or did you just increase from `64M`to `265M` in one jump?

Comment: I did `128M` with no luck so went up to `256M` I just tried `150M` and it worked fine but I'd like some flexibility to upload 10MB+ images.

Answer (score -1):

Look in the php.ini at

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 40M
```

Change 40M to your max size

Comment: The question specifies that the issue is with `memory_limit` and is fixed by using `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');` So what has `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size` got to do with this question?